# Modal not shown but nothing is clickable on page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap 4 modal which is shown the first time a page is loaded.  A cookie is set after that first time which hides the modal on load.  The first time the site is loaded, everything works fine even after you close the modal.  However, subsequent page loads, when the modal is not shown, for some reason nothing is clickable on the page.  It has something to do with the z-index, because I'm able to set the z-index of individual elements (ie the nav bar) really high and then they become clickable...I just want to avoid having to go through and put a z-index on every single element.

Here is the code deciding whether or not the modal is shown.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        if (!<?php echo $modalCookie; ?> && !<?php echo $showOnce; ?>) {
            $('#aboutModal').modal('show');
        }
}
```

Here is a link to the site with the issue: https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/indicators/vt

Let me know if there's any other info that may be helpful...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing to hide the popup is to reduce it's opacity to 0, but the element still takes space in the screen even if you cannot see it. It's transparent now, but it's actually showing.

You could fix this issue by using `display: none` to hide it instead.

```
/* Don't show modal by default */
#aboutModal {
  display: none; 
  padding-right: 17px;
}

/* Only display modal when it has class .show */
#aboutModal.show {
  display: block; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this css seemed to do the trick.

```
.fade:not(.show) {
    z-index: -1;
}
```